# Android studio Gradle project scope dependency

Tags: android, gradle, module, dependencies, project

I have multiple modules and every module uses exact same dependency. Because it is annoying to maintain that dependency in all build.gradle files (version updates etc.) I'd like to have it in project build.gradle. Is that possible please?

I tried to:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'          
        compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.8.1'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

but that doesn't work as it seems that gradle is not able to find DSL for compile. Is there any other way please?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

It's called centralize the support libraries dependencies in gradle. Working with multi-modules project, it is very useful to centralize the dependencies, especially the support libraries.

http://gmariotti.blogspot.in/2015/07/how-to-centralize-support-libraries.html

Comment: Seems legit.Though I was looking if there is a way to have it written only in top level build.gradle and put it to allprojects part or something :)

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if i'm wrong but what's inside buildscript are dependencies for build.

When I generate my project build.gradle there is note :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.getkeepsafe.dexcount:dexcount-gradle-plugin:0.1.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

So no, you can't put dependencies for all your module here but maybe there is a plugin for that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot centralize the dependencies for all (sub-)projects, but is is very easy to centralize the version numbers. In `build.gradle` in the root add this:

```
ext {
    jodaTimeVersion = '2.8.1'
}
```

And in `build.gradle` of the modules that need Joda-Time add this (pay attention to the double quotes):

```
dependencies {
    compile "joda-time:joda-time:${jodaTimeVersion}"
}
```